# minmax() in CSS grid layout

Tags: html, css, css-grid, grid-layout

I'm facing some issues with the `minmax()` function related to CSS grid layout.

Here is my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 250px) 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 95, 107);
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: rgba(0, 95, 107, 0.8);
  padding: 0.2em;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
</div>
```

When I use `minmax()` with `fr` unit as mentioned in my CSS, width of grid tracks get the max value, and stay in the max size even if I reduce the viewport; but when I used it with `px` as follows

```css
grid-template-columns: minmax(150px, 250px) 200px 200px;
```

It works as expected, I don't know why.

Tested on: Chrome and Firefox

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with your code. This seems to be the standard behaviour of `minmax` when combined with columns that use the `fr` unit because the `fr` unit has no minimum value (except the width of its content which is here almost empty – just a single digit).

If there is enough screen space `minmax` will take up its maximum value.

If you were to increase the maximum value in `minmax` and then adjust your browser window you'll notice that `minmax` is working, and that when there is not enough space for it to be at its maximum width, its width *will* decrease.